# Words representations of elements of a symmetric group

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $S=\{(1,2),(1,2,\ldots,n),(1,n,,n-1,\ldots,2)\}$ be a subset of the symmetric group $S_n$. Let $a=(1,2),b=(1,2,\ldots,n),c=(1,n,n-1\ldots,2)$ be the elements of $S$. My question is, since $S$ is a generating set of $S_n$, what are the distinct shortest words in the set $S$ that enunciate all the elements of $S_n$. That is, how do we describe one set of distinct words which give rise to all the elements of $S_n$; or, I want one set of $n!$ minimal words(with exponents of each letter being positive) which give the elements of $S_n$.

Since the word problem on finite groups is solvable, I think there would be a way to enunciate all such elements. Since only $a,b$ are sufficient to generate the whole group, so I was thinking along the lines of $a, ba,b^2a,\ldots,b^{n-1}a=ca,ab,ab^2,\ldots ab^{n-1}=ac,aba,abab,abab^2,\ldots,abab^{n-1}=abac\ldots$. Is there a right way to enunciate such words? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Just think about the cycle decomposition of elements of $S_n$.  Moreover, you do not need $c$, i.e. $\{a,b\}$ generates.

Comment: Each element of $S_n$ can be expressed in infinitely many different ways as a word in the generators. So you need to be more precise in what you are asking. You could ask for a shortest word representing each element (which is still not unique), or you might prefer something with a more concise description.

Comment: @DerekHolt yes, I want the shortest word for representing each element

Comment: @vidyarthi could you edit your question to make it more clear? for the moment "how do we describe all those distinct combinations which give rise to all the elements of $S_n$" is too general, and the thread of comments is not the right place to amend a question.

Comment: In that case you should edit the question to make it clear what you are asking. In any case "the shortest word" is still not unique.

Comment: After doing a few computer experiments in $S_6$,  I am doubtful whether there is a concise description of a set of shortest words for the group elements. For a example, a shortest word for $(2,6,3,4,5)$ is $bab^{-1}ababab^{-1}a$, and a shortest word for $(2,6,4,3)$ is $b^2ab^{-2}ab^{-1}$.  The finite state automaton that accepts the set of shortlex least words has $162$ states.

Comment: @YCor edited the question again

Comment: @DerekHolt yes, that is the sort of description I want. By the way, which software you are using to do the calculations? Is it SageMath, or GAP? What commands you use, if it is sage?

Comment: In the way you edited, it seems unclear to me if you're asking for an explicit list of $n!$ words representing all elements, or if you're asking the same with the explicit constraint that in addition consists of words of minimal length. Without the additional requirement, it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @YCor added a word now. I hope it is well posed now.

Comment: About solvability of the word problem for finite groups: this means that each finite group has an algorithm and means that for each individual $n$ you have such a subset, which is essentially void information. You need some uniformity, and indeed the word problem is uniformly solvable for this family of finite groups and generating subset. So yes, there is an algorithm with will output as a list for growing $n$ such subsets (and it's not hard to make such an algorithm explicit; just use some lexicographic order to choose representatives). Of course I suppose you expect something more explicit.

Comment: @YCor actually, I want such a rule to build my words- we start with $a,b$; then we have $ab, ab^2...,ab^{n-1},bab,bab^2,....,bab^{n-1}...$ as one way of buliding, the other way would be $ba,b^2a,...,b^{n-1}a,aba,ab^2a,...,ab^{n-1}a$ as another way of building. So the question boils down to when should we stop in such a building of words so as to get all the desired elements. Note that I wish that all exponents of generating letters be positive

Comment: But there's no minimal representative of $b^{-1}$ that is a positive word (indeed its length should be 1, but $b^{-1}$ is not among the generators if $n\ge 4$). So it's impossible, unless you mean minimal positive words.

Comment: @YCor But, I have $c=b^{-1}$ right?

Comment: @vidyarthi oh, sorry, I misread $c$. So your generating subset is symmetric and hence every group word is automatically positive (after replacing $a^{-1},b^{-1},c^{-1}$ with $a,c,b$ if necessary. So no need to worry about positivitity (assuming you mean $\ge 0$).

Comment: If you were prepared to change generating set to the $n-1$ elements $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),\ldots,(n-1,n)$ each of order two there is a very good geometric theory of word length with respect to these generators.  The thing to search for is finite Coxeter groups: the symmetric group $S_n$ with these generators is the Coxeter group of type $A_{n-1}$.  For example, there is a unique element of $S_n$ that has maximal length with respect to these generators (although there are many words of that length that represent it).  The geometry behind this is that the antipodal point on a sphere is unique.

Comment: @IJL Yes, I know that with respect to transposition generators, there is lot of freedom and symmetry in word representations. But, I expect a similar program for this set of minimal generators, which has the least cardinality(excluding the element $b$ or $c$)

Answer (score 3):

The diameter of the Cayley graph of $S_n$ with respect to $a=(1,2)$, $b=(1,2,\dots,n)$, and $c=b^{-1}=(n,n-1,n-2,\dots,1)$ is not known.

See the sequence [A186783](https://oeis.org/A186783) on OEIS.

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07342) may be of interest (it gives an algorithm for producing the "flip" permutation $(1,n)(2,n-1),(3,n-2),\dots$ in $O(n^2)$ steps.